# jq: Testing if a key is in a list of predefined keys

Tags: json, key, jq, any

I have a case where I need to parse quoted JSON in JSON.
I know which *optional* attributes will contain quoted JSON and which not.
Therefore, I want to check if the attribute keys are in a list of possible keys. I already have the following:

```
# attributes "a" and "b" contain quoted JSON
echo '{"a":"{\"x\":1}","y":2}' |
jq -c '
   def is_json($o): ["a","b"] | (map(select(. == $o)) | length) > 0;
   with_entries(if is_json(.key) then .value = (.value|fromjson) else . end)
'
```

This already produces the desired output: `{"a":{"x":1},"y":2}`. However, the checking of the attribute name looks clumsy, given that `jq` provides a lot built-in functions such as `has`, `in`, `contains`, `inside`, etc.

**Question:** Is there a better way of checking if an attribute key is in a given list?

**Edit:** Here is the current solution, based on peak's answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
to_array_string() { echo "$*" | awk -v OFS='","' 'NF > 0 {$1=$1; print "\""$0"\""}'; }
to_json_array_string() { echo "["`to_array_string "$@"`"]"; }

parse_json_jq() { jq -c "
   reduce keys[] as \$key
   (.; if any((`to_array_string "$@"`); . == \$key) and .[\$key] != null then .[\$key] |= fromjson else . end)
";}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways in which your program can be improved:

1. (efficiency) avoiding the creation of an unnecessary array (in `is_json`);
2. (efficiency) using "short-circuit" semantics to avoid
   iterating unnecessarily;
3. (efficiency) avoid the construction/deconstruction involved with with_entries;

For the most part, I think you will agree that the alternatives offered here are simpler, more concise, or more readable.

If you have version 1.5 of jq or later, the main improvements
can be had using any/2:

```
def is_json($o): any( ("a","b"); . == $o );

with_entries(if is_json(.key) then .value |= fromjson else . end)
```

Notice also the use of '|=' where you had used '='.

If your jq does not have `any/2`, then you could use the following
definition, though it lacks short-circuit semantics:

```
def any(s): reduce s as $i (false; . == true or $i);
```

Finally, to avoid using `with_entries`, you could use `reduce` and eliminate `is_json` entirely:

```
reduce keys[] as $key
  (.; if any(("a","b"); . == $key) then .[$key] |= fromjson else . end)
```

Comment: Thx for this solution. I just needed to add another `null` check to make it work (see edit to the question).